Validate python asyncio running asynchronously
I have a function the takes in an html string, cleans it by removing stop words, and then counts the number of occurrences of words within a user-determined search string:
def clean_text(string, search_term):
    """
    This function removes stop words and non alphanumeric characters from a string and counts the number of times each word in a specified search term appears in the string.
    :param string: the string to clean
    :param search_term:
    """
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(string)
    alpha_string = [word.lower() for word in word_tokens if word.isalpha()]
    cleaned_string = [word.lower() for word in alpha_string if word.lower() not in stop_words]
    
    c = Counter(cleaned_string)
    total_freq = np.sum([c[i] for i in search_term.lower().split()])
    
    if total_freq == 0:
        return (0, 0)
    else:
        return " ".join(cleaned_string), total_freq

I am trying to turn this into an asynchronous function using python's asyncio. I have the below code:
async def clean_text_async(string, search_term):
    """
    This function removes stop words and non alphanumeric characters from a string and counts the number of times each word in a specified search term appears in the string.
    :param string: the string to clean
    :param search_term:
    """
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(string)
    alpha_string = [word.lower() for word in word_tokens if word.isalpha()]
    cleaned_string = [word.lower() for word in alpha_string if word.lower() not in stop_words]
    
    c = Counter(cleaned_string)
    total_freq = np.sum([c[i] for i in search_term.lower().split()])
    
    if total_freq == 0:
        return (0, 0)
    else:
        return " ".join(cleaned_string), total_freq
    
async def async_main_html(df_html):
    clean_text_tasks = []
    
    for html in df_html['html']:
        task = asyncio.create_task(clean_text_async(string = html, search_term = search_term))
        clean_text_tasks.append(task)
        
    results = await asyncio.gather(*clean_text_tasks)
    return results

cleaned_text = await async_main_html(df_html)

The code works and runs using the above commands, but I don't believe it's running asynchronously, as the function takes the same amount of time to run using both async_main_html and clean_text.
Am I doing something wrong?

You don't have any await in clean_text_async() - in this example you've posted you will probably be better using multiprocessing.

@AndrejKesely -- interesting ok. so i need to have await in each async function? i guess i'm confused as to how in my example i use await in the first function.

Asynchronous functions are useful if they have to wait for something, usually for receiving/sending data over a network or from/to a hard-drive. A function that all the time uses the CPU isn't suitable for that (because there is nothing to await for). Better try multiprocessing as recommended.

You are not getting what asynchronous programming do - in fact it would have no benefit for this code at all!
Asynchronous code is single threaded, and just allows code to run concurrently when one task has to wait for an outside source (filesystem, database, HTTP API, etc...) to provide data. At the point it will get the data it uses an await statement (or equivalent), and while that data is not ready, other tasks have the opportunity to run.
Your code just does processing - there is no point in there it would make sense to use an await statement - so there is no point in running it asynchronously at first.
There is a scenario where it could benefit, at least a little, however: if this processing is taking place as part of processing a request in an API, and there might be several of those to take care at once, asyncio might be used to run certain of the CPU bound processing in other threads. Since the regexp engine, and string methods, in Python run in native code, they will free the GIL, allowing string operations to run in parallel, in the background, to some extent - and you could get some improvements - IF you are issuing several of these tasks at once. The time to complete a single task, however, would go unchanged.
If you opt to re-structure your code this way, instead of changing the clean_text  to a co-routine function, as you have done, just leave it as is (synchronous, with a plain def instead of async def), but call it from the async code by using an  asyncio.create_task(asyncio.run_in_executor(None, clean_text, *args)) call.
If that works to some extent, you might want to fine-tune a custom "executor" instead of using the default one with None to extract some extra bits of performance. For example, using a ProcessPoolExecutor  instead of the default ThreadPoolExecutor will ensure all the code can run in parallel in other processor core - however, it will also introduce an overhead for data serialization/de-serialization when it is passed back and forth to the workers processes -ultimately, you have to benchmark different executor parameters to get the best setup for your data and hardware configuration.
